# Masonite getting error H10 when deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

I am deploying my Masonite app to Heroku but it keeps saying application crashed.

This is the error in the Heroku logs:

> 2019-01-15T16:55:36.759023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET
>   path="/api/document/get_from_array?document_kinds,ID_CARD,TAX_ID,SELFIE&profile_id,2&user_id,8&provider_id,6"
>   host=sibyl-core.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=10-12-27161 fwd="196.57.188.111"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

This works on localhost but not on Heroku.

This is what the response shows on localhost:

```
{
    "ID_CARD": [],
    "TAX_ID": [],
    "SELFIE": []
}
```

I am using Gunicorn for my WSGI server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time this happens because of 2 reasons:

1. Your Procfile is incorrect
2. Your requirements.txt is not up to date.

Typically it is number 2 but if you are deploying with Gunicorn then your procfile should be:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:application
```

If that looks correct to you then run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And then try redeploying. The `pip freeze` will ensure that your requirements.txt is up to date with all dependencies in your current environment.